# Windows mobile 7 listbox.. add items from a string split operation

Tags: c#, string, listbox, split

I have a var return from a webservice in this string format-

> [{"Age":"20","Term":"10","Mode":"Yearly","SA":"25000","ADBRAge":"20","ADBRTerm":"10","ADBRSA":"25000","IP":"56321","Name":"someone","Advisor":"someon","Sex":"Male","date":"20-12-2010","DOC":"20-12-2010","DOB":"20-12-1984","ADBRIP":"250123"}]

can anyone help me or tell how do i split it... and create a listbox from all the items like
age : 20
term : 10
on windows phone 7 and c# as the language.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), you can use `DataContractJsonSerializer` to parse it. Check this article: [WP7: How to consume JSON data on a Windows Phone 7 application](http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/11/wp7-how-to-consume-json-data-from.html)